# Monitoring Ethereum private network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I've created a private Ethereum network and would like to explore the monitoring.  I started a `geth` instance in one terminal window.  I tried running `geth monitor --attach /path/to/geth.ipc` and receive the following error:

`Fatal: Metric pattern trie/cachemiss resolved to unexpected type: string`

What is the best way to go about monitoring the node(s) on my private network?

Answer (score 5):

You should point out metrics in command line: `geth monitor --attach ./chain-data/geth.ipc system/memory/allocs/AvgRate05Min`

Important prerequisite is that geth must be started with `--metrics`

More details https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring my private network, I use a self hosted site similar to ethstats.net

- First I host an empty site using https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats
- Then I install an [API](https://github.com/cubedro/eth-net-intelligence-api) which will send the data from my node to the site.

Detailed instructions can be found on [my post](https://ayushyachitransh.wordpress.com/2018/04/21/setting-up-monitoring-for-ethereum-network/)